# How do I allow new system preferences in profile manager?

Tags: system-settings, profile-manager

We're using Profile Manager on our group of Macs.  The System Preferences options are setup as a whitelist.  However, the profile manager doesn't know about certain options, so they get blocked by default when I'd like to be able to enable them (Example: Java Control Panel and Wacom Tablet settings).

Is there a way to tell Profile Manager that those things exist so that I can enable them (and keep the whitelisting model)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the 3rd party control panel onto the Mac running the server - then they appear to be allowed or not.